# Create a list of all SSIS tasks with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ssis, task

I want to automatically create a list of all tasks from an SSIS dtsx package using PowerShell.

I tried opening the dtsx file and analyse it step by step but I think there might be a better and more efficient way?

Any help would be great! Maybe there already is an answer I didn't find.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is not exactly a duplicate, but this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2106148/307138

Comment: thank you but I already tried the SSIS extension, I always got an error message. I will try it again

Comment: If you get an error message, post your code and the message, maybe somebody here can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Powershell is an ideal tool to extract information form SSIS packages. The DTSX file is just a namespaced XML file. You can load it into a variable like so:

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $_)
$ns = [System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager]($xml.NameTable)
$ns.AddNamespace("DTS", "www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts")
```

You then use XAPTH to extract the information you need like so:

```
$xml.SelectNodes("//component", $ns)
```

Comment: Thank you Dave! This is a good idea! But I still don't get it running. The XML File uses "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DTS:Executable xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"
  ..............Do I have to use "DTS:Executable" insted from "DTS"? And the node I want to read is "DTS:ObjectName" from: <DTS:Executables>
    <DTS:Executable
      DTS:refId="Package\Get Date Range"
      DTS:CreationName="Microsoft.ExecuteSQLTask"
      DTS:Description="Task 'SQL ausführen'"

Comment: I posted a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353355/create-a-word-list-of-all-tasks-in-a-dtsx-file-ssis-with-powershell